# hibernate how to retrieve a hierarchy object

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following beans Task, ServerDetails and ApplicationDetails.
I wish to retrieve all tasks, their server details and application details based on a specific application name.

From the result i expect to be able to retrieve the data in a manner such as: 
task.getServers().getApplicationDetails()

In actuality, I get what seems to be flat data's representation as an Object[].

Is there any way to do what i propose?

Following is my code...

```
class Task {
    private String taskId;
    private Set<ServerDetails> servers;
}

class ServerDetails {
    private String id;
    private Set<ApplicationDetails> applications;
}

class ApplicationDetails {
   private String id;
}
```

HQL:

```
StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder(256);
hql.append("FROM Task h, ServerDetails ser, ApplicationDetails app ");
hql.append("WHERE h.executionDate > "); 
hql.append("to_date('");
hql.append(DBDateFormatter.getInstance().formatDate(cal));
hql.append("',  '");
hql.append(DBDateFormatter.getInstance().getOracleDateFormat());
hql.append("') and h.id = ser.task.id and ser.id = app.server and app.name = 'XXX'");
hql.append(" order by h.executionDate desc");
String hql = hql.toString();

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);      
results = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just retrieve the main object.

For the other, you can:

1. navigate to them while the `Session` has not be closed (runs additional queries as needed, known as lazy ; this is ideal for ease of use)
2. retrieve them in the original query using the `fetch` keyword.

Example:

```
    SELECT h 
    FROM Task h
    JOIN FETCH h.serveurs ser
    JOIN FETCH ser.applications app 
    WHERE h.executionDate > 
    .... // no need to specify the joins
```

You will be able to retrieve the data in a manner such as:
`task.getServers().getApplicationDetails()`

Comment: +1. Three things to keep in mind here: (a) the above select should use **LEFT** join fetch unless you're 100% sure you always have servers / applications populated; (b) it may return duplicate `Task` instances so resulting list should be filtered (wrapped in Set, for example); and (c) using `to_date()` and formatting dates is completely unnecessary - specify it as parameter and set it on query as actual Date instead.

Comment: Hi,

I want to add to the hql something like that:
hqlQ.append("LEFT JOIN FETCH h.prompts p on (h.id = p.task.id and p.applicationName in (" + apps.toString() + ")) "
do you have idea how to do it?

Comment: @Keren Between 'h' and 'p', the relation seem to go through 'task', that would be easier. For the 'applicationName', it belongs to the 'where' part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the object graph as the others have said using LEFT JOIN FECH. One crevent I have found when retrieving object graphs, when walking down a many-to-one relationship you can not walk back up without additional database access.